# Can I start react native development with android SDK and AVD only on Ubuntu?

Tags: android, ubuntu, react-native

Is it possible to start developing android apps with React Native by installing android SDK and AVD manager but without installing android studio?
I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and already installed Android SDK and AVD manager.

Comment: I think you can do if you install android SDK Tools and some commands lines as I mentioned below

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as I know RN needs XCode only when you want to start the iOS App.

On this [page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) if you select Android and Linux you will get the steps to install RN and how to configure the project.

Comment: My question was about without installing Android Studio in Ubuntu. Since I can work on android development seamlessly with only running AVD manager to run the emulator in Windows 10. I don't need to use Android Studio here in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think its possible to start writing apps in react-native without installing android studio. Probably for such you would require installing a virtual android device then rest would work.

I hope you've installed the following things:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

Then to me you will have to install Android SDK tools that's necessary. Once you've installed the react-native-cli then set **Environment Variables** that can via opening terminal and type:

```
sudo vi ~/.bash_profile
```

then put this code:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Then run:

```
react-native run-android
react-native start
```

Let's try out and confirm